# How to make a random number 4 characters long - Java

Tags: java, string, random, int

I need to generate a random number between 0 and 9999 and then I need to make the numbers all four characters long - so if 1238 is generated its fine, but if 96 is generated it needs to display 0096, or 3 will be 0003

Here is my code so far...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i = i++) {
        int randomInteger = randomGenerator.nextInt(9999);
        System.out.println(randomInteger);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `System.out.printf("%04d ", randomInteger);`

Comment: Thankyou! i also need to make it so it doesnt use 1111,2222,3333,4444 ect to 9999 how do i do this?

Comment: Your question didn't say anything about that at all. Could you please update your question (using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33827593/edit) link) to explain all of your requirements clearly? For example, you want random numbers between what and what? And what kinds of numbers do you want to avoid?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.format()` to do so. In your case you can do

```
System.out.println(String.format("%04d",randomInteger));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.format("%04d", randomInteger)
```

Comment: Please avoid `toString()'.  `%04d` needs an integer.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are correct, but if you really don't want to use String formatting function, you can try below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int min  = 1000;    
        int max = 9999;
       Random r = new Random();
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i = i++) {
             randomInteger = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
             System.out.println(randomInteger);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would this solution produce `0003` or `0096` which are examples given by the OP?